# How do I create a form in django that selects instances of another django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to django and so far I've created these models. `Climb` represents climbing routes with names, week, grade, and points associated if completed and a `Climber` model that has `climbs_completed`, which is a collection of `Climb`. My question is how do I create a django form that displays the existing `Climb` objects with a checkbox so that the user can select which `Climb` he/she has completed and save it to their `climbs_completed` field?

```
class Climb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    grades = [('v'+str(i),'v'+str(i))for i in range(0,13)]
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=grades, default='v-1')
    weeks = [(i,i)for i in range(1,13)]
    week = models.IntegerField(choices=weeks, default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Climber(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grades = [('v'+str(i),'v'+str(i))for i in range(0,13)]
    highest_grade = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=grades, default='v0')
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    climbs_completed = models.ManyToManyField(Climb, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    # for each climbs_completed, sum up the points
    @property
    def total_score(self):
        return self.climbs_completed.aggregate(total_score=Sum('points'))['total_score']
```

Comment: take a look of `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: Maybe even better the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` then the user can add multiple climbes at once, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield)